# GICP usage in PCL

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have looked for how to implement Generalized ICP(GICP) with PCL. I found a sample code in [test/registration/test_registration.cpp](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/test/registration/test_registration.cpp) in PCL repository on github. The sample code uses GICP as following. Could you tell me following procedure is correct one to use GICP with PCL?

The fucntion "align" is a function of IterativeClosestPoint class. It means that "align" does not consider point-to-plane that AV Segal et al refer in their paper. I'm wondering if this is a correct procedure to use GICP with PCL. In addition, I don't know why PCL does not provide us sample codes which use estimateRigidTransformationBFGS the metod of GeneralizedIterativeClosestPoint class.

```
GeneralizedIterativeClosestPoint<PointT, PointT> reg_guess;
reg_guess.setInputSource (src);
reg_guess.setInputTarget (transformed_tgt);
reg_guess.setMaximumIterations (50);
reg_guess.setTransformationEpsilon (1e-8);
reg_guess.align (output, transform.matrix ());
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the usage! Autonomous system lab in ETH Zurich opens it in their github repository. Please check [robust_point_cloud_registration](https://github.com/ethz-asl/robust_point_cloud_registration)!

Answer (score 0):

Check this article https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7271006

Registration with the Point Cloud Library: A Modular Framework for Aligning in 3-D, Dirk Holz; Alexandru E. Ichim; Federico Tombari; Radu B. Rusu; Sven Behnke

They show an example of using GICP

Answer (score 0):

Actually, align function calls `estimateRigidTransformationBFGS` in its internal. the function call  sequence is `Registration::align()->GeneralizedIterativeClosestPoint::computeTransformation()->GeneralizedIterativeClosestPoint::rigid_transformation_estimation_().computeTransformation()` is a pure virtual function in Registration class and is implement in `GeneralizedIterativeClosestPoint class finally;rigid_transformation_estimation_()` is bind to `estimateRigidTransformationBFGS()` in `GeneralizedIterativeClosestPoint` Construction function. So there is no need to call `estimateRigidTransformationBFGS()` by ourself.